# How can I find the nearest points (plural) on a line segment using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I'm locating the nearest point on a line segment with PostGIS and [ST_ClosestPoint](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_ClosestPoint.html), I can select the point on each of these line segments which is closest to the starting point. Which looks something like this:

[image: Find nearest point on segment]

But! I cannot figure out how to get the second closest point, or the third closest point on a given segment.

What I would like is more like this:

[image: Find multiple points on each segment]

I'd like a range of nearby points on the line segments.

Any thoughts about how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Can you explain the criteria for nearby points on the line segment is in your second diagram? The nearest point in your first diagram is a perpendicular from each line to the point; in the second digram it's not clear what these points are.

Comment: ah, I didn't mean to make it perpendicular. I've updated the original question.

Comment: There is an unlimited amount of potential points on a line. Do you want a minimum spacing between the points?

Comment: @underdark you're correct. maybe a spacing of 1m? or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ST_DumpPoints() and ORDER BY...LIMIT 3 in your query can get what you want. It might go:

```
SELECT ST_AsText( (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom ) 
FROM  your_line
ORDER BY ST_Distance(SetSrid(MakePoint(your_X,your_Y), SRID),  (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom ) ASC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: if a line segment is defined by two points i.e. `LINESTRING ( 0 3, 3 4 )` will this return just the end points?

Comment: Try it:  `SELECT ST_AsText( (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom ) 
FROM  LineStringFromText('LINESTRING(0 3,3 4)',4326) AS geom
ORDER BY ST_Distance(SetSrid(MakePoint(2,2), 4326),  (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom ) ASC LIMIT 3;`  returns: POINT(3 3) POINT(3 4)